# Expanding dimension of numpy array by slicing

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a huge numpy array `X` of dimensions `(28000, 96, 96, 4)`. In addition, I have an 1D array `users` of size 28000 which contains 28000 string entries, each string entry is denoting a specific users. For example:

```
X = numpy.random.rand(28000,96,96,4)
users = ["john"]*5666
users.extend(["doe"]*8421)
users.extend(["lea"]*3001)
users.extend(["rambo"]*10912)
users = numpy.array(users)
```

In this example, there are only 4 users, but actually, I have 80 users.

Now I would like to create an additional dimension by slicing through the array, so that the final dimension will be `(28000, n, 96, 96, 4)`. For each user I would like to form the new dimension by slicing over `n` elements, so for example for `n = 3`

```
Y[0,:,96,96,4] = X[0:2,:,:,:] # User John
Y[1,:,96,96,4] = X[1:3,:,:,:] # User John
Y[2,:,96,96,4] = X[2:4,:,:,:] # User John
...
Y[5663,:,96,96,4] = X[5663:5665,:,:,:] # User John
Y[5664,:,96,96,4] = X[5666:5668,:,:,:] # New user (Doe)
Y[5665,:,96,96,4] = X[5667:5669,:,:,:] # User Doe
...
Y[14083,:,96,96,4] = X[14085:14087,:,:,:] # User Doe
Y[14084,:,96,96,4] = X[14088:14091,:,:,:] # New user (lea)
...
```

As can be seen, the first `n` elements of each user are skipped.

Is there an efficient way to do this for general `n` (in terms of runtime and memory consumption)? I don't need the original array `X` anymore, so perhaps it could be done inline.

Comment: Each `X` slice has shape (2,96,96,4), so `Y` shape should be (28000,2,96,94,4).  I don't think the `user` groupings make a difference.  If my picture is right I think `X` can be viewed in the `Y` shape with `as_strided`, but working out the strides will require some thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X = np.random.rand(28000,96,96,4)

Y = np.zeros((28000,2,96,96,4))
for i in range(28000):
    Y[i] = X[i:i+2]

strides = X.strides
strides = (strides[0],)+strides
Z = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strides(X, Y.shape, strides=strides)
```

test this with

```
np.allclose(Y,Z)
```

I tested part of this with a much smaller `X`, and setting just a few lines of `Y` (your full `X` is too large for my machine).